# Tags in Marketing Cloud Campaings

Tags: marketing-cloud, campaign

Is there a way to create Analytics Builder reports basing on campaign tags? I don't see such an option in the following reports related to campaigns:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_re_campaign_email_tracking_report.htm&type=5#mc_re_campaign_email_tracking_report

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_re_multi_campaign_email_tracking_summary.htm&type=5#mc_re_multi_campaign_email_tracking_summary

and I cannot see it in Discover reports. 
So are campaign tags relevant for reporting in any way?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue before and the only way to retrieve the tag of a campaign was asking Support to create a custom view.